# Are inner struct/class declarations automatically friend of the nesting class?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I've come over a little discussion today, whether it's necessary to explicitly declare `friend` access for an inner `class`/`struct`. Here's the (replicating sample) code in question:

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

class Implementation
{
    struct InterfaceImpl : Interface
    {
        InterfaceImpl(Implementation* impl)
        : impl_(impl) {}
        virtual void foo() 
        { 
            impl_->doFoo(); // << Here's what's in question!!
        } 

        Implementation* impl_;
    };

public:
    Implementation()
    : interfaceImpl_(this) {}

    Interface* getInterface() { return &interfaceImpl_; }

private:
    InterfaceImpl interfaceImpl_;

    void doFoo() {}
};
```

---

```
int main() {
    Implementation impl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've been noticing that the code compiles well, where I thought it would be necessary to have a `friend struct InterfaceImpl;` at the `Implementation`class to get it working. So the following setups all work fine: [c++11](http://ideone.com/zoosnW), [GCC 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/XEc0oX), [GCC 4.3.2](http://ideone.com/nNtFh0).

Is there a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)  (pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) standard section that confirms this is legal?

Comment: Voted to leave closed specifically because you're **demanding** your own question be reopened.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not quite sure how this is different from the dupe... would you mind telling me?

Comment: I'm asking for having this question reopened, since (vs. the dupe) it consolidates all of the standard concerns (and mentions the GCC exception [which I've been tagging!!] ) nicely! It mainly differs from the given tags (relevance), and the relation for that explained exceptional behavior of GCC 4.3.2  behavior.

Comment: You can read all this as answered here (somehow) from the jungle in the proposed dupe, but by relevance of the given tags this particular Q/A might either stand on it's own, or outweigh the recommended dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not `friend`s *per se* (so your interpretation is subtly wrong), but the effect you've seen is definitely standard-mandated:

> `[C++11: 11.7/1]:` A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. *[..]*

The example given at this point in the standard is similar to yours.

*However*, this was not legal in C++03!

> `[C++03: 11.8/1]:` The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class, nor to classes or functions that have granted friendship to an enclosing class; the usual access rules (clause 11) shall be obeyed. *[..]*

[This was considered to be a defect in the standard as early as 1998 (and made into DR #45 in 2001)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45), which may go some way to explaining why you're seeing non-compliant behaviour in GCC, pre-C++11. In that sense, we might see the new C++11 wording as catching up with a long-standing practical reality.

Comment: THX! That explains it! That's, what one of my other colleagues intuitively assumed, right away! **Time** to remove these unnecessary `friend` declarations everywhere ;-) (also these one's didn't hurt anything anyway )...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If it makes you feel any better, I'd have had to look it up anyway. :)

Comment: Awww!! I've been too lazy right now (**shame** on me), makes me feel worse just right now ;-) ...

Comment: **Hmmm** there's still that GCC 4.3.2 sample (which doesn't really should guarantee c++11 standards). Was this one of the ubiquitous GCC extensions then?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this wasn't officially the case before C++11. (I always thought it was, since that was how GCC had worked for many years, and was quite surprised to find it wasn't.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Hmm, okay; while true, I wouldn't feel comfortable adding that into my answer until I can adequately explain why & how GCC ignored the C++03 rule.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good mention, since I think the given code (including the `friend` declarations) was also be supposed to be compiled with non GCC compliant c++ compilers ('embedded' crappy stuff maybe ...). As it stands, referring to [tag:c++11] standard is the only really reliable thing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've slightly edited my question ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Pre C++11, there's certainly a standard section confirming that it's *not* legal. But I only have a paper copy of C++03, and that's in my office several miles away, so I can't provide the exact quote.

Comment: @MikeSeymour _'confirming that it's not legal ...'_ Good hint anyway! I'll research further ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit **Note:** I'm asking for **definite** differences of [tag:c++03] and [tag:c++11].

Comment: This was considered to be a defect in C++98 and was fixed long time ago [issue 45](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Your question now says "pre-C++11". It didn't before. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, sorry!! I wasn't clear enough (puzzled by the GCC 4.3.2 case).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't have the knowledge Mike has about that. However, I've added the relevant legalese for C++03.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That makes it acceptable as valid answer again! (Sorry I'm that lazy, again ;) )

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As a small side note: I'm not seeing any non-compliant behavior for GCC, but suspect there were other compilers concerned when the nested struct/class declarations were marked as `friend` explicitly. I know, some of the code in question had to deal with such stuff as using some weird compiler implementation (earlier).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To elaborate: Kind of c++ compiler crap like [Metrowerks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrowerks) etc. pp. ...